# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

May be this is a duplicate question but I was unable to find any reference.
I am following https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html and using ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz model.
I am getting error while executing this line of code: `!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=/content/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=/content/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet_v1_fpn/pipeline.config`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 112, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 609, in train_loop
    train_input, unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 400, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
    _ensure_model_is_built(model, input_dataset, unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 178, in _ensure_model_is_built
    labels,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1316, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2892, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 678, in _call_for_each_replica
    self._container_strategy(), fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py", line 86, in call_for_each_replica
    return wrapped(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node ResNet101V1_FPN/model/conv1_conv/Conv2D
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py:238)
]] [Op:__inference__dummy_computation_fn_24454]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node ResNet101V1_FPN/model/conv1_conv/Conv2D:
In[0] ResNet101V1_FPN/model/lambda/Pad (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/keras_models/resnet_v1.py:51) 
In[1] ResNet101V1_FPN/model/conv1_conv/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp:

.....................
.....................
```

Tried below to resolve the issue but didn't worked out.

1. tensorlow-gpu version is 2.7.0.I tried downgrading the version to 2.4.1 but not worked.
2. tried installing opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30
3. Ran the cmd -> `physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU') if len(physical_devices) > 0: tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)`
4. also, `os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'`
5. Updated Batch size to 8.

Using Google Colab to execute the notebook.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you check that GPU is well selected in the notebook parameters for execution ?

Comment: @LCMa, yes it is selected. I have also 30gb free on the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Referred https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10107 for more idea.
I removed one image(guess the extension was wrong for it) and then ran the command `python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_efficientdet_d0_512x512_coco17_tpu-8.config --model_dir=training --alsologtostderr` instead of `!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=/content/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=/content/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet_v1_fpn/pipeline.config`. And hurray, my model is training now.